# How to match type of instance in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

I was trying to assert exception type in a test using Matchers (don't ask why) and the solution that I got is this:

```
exception.getClass shouldBe classOf[FileNotFoundException]
```

But it looks super ugly, is there a better way?

Bye

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use `intercept` method:

```
val exception = intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
  List.empty[String].head // Code that throws exception
}

exception.getMessage shouldBe "head of empty list"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you the "an [] should be thrownBy" matcher:

```
 an [IllegalArgumentException] should be thrownBy {
    //code that should raise an exception here
 }
```

Make sure your test class includes the "Matchers":

```
class MyTestClass extends FunSuite with Matchers
```